# Pass an ID through a series of functions one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple images.

```
<img src="fruits/lychee.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl156">
<img src="fruits/cranberry.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl141">
<img src="fruits/avocado.png" class ="fruit" id="fruitl214">
```

When the page loads a random number of images will be visible. I want to pass each visible image ID through a series of functions one at a time.

```
var ID = '';
$('#getIDs').click(function(){
   ID = $('.fruit:visible').map(function () {
      return this.id;
   }).get();
});
```

These are the series of functions I want to pass each ID at a time.

```
function showInfo( anID, var2, var3 ){
    //do something 
    getThumbs( anID, newvar1);
});
function getThumbs( anID, newvar1){
    //do something
    showRates( anID, anothervar1, anotherVar2); 
});
function showRates( anID, anothervar1, anotherVar2){
    //do something 
});
```

So when the first ID has gone through all functions the second ID is sent through the functions, so on... How can I do this?

EDIT:

It is a chain of functions. Each function triggers the next function.

Comment: seems like `map` also not needed, use simple `each`

Comment: In this case it is better to use  `$('.fruit:visible').map(function () {
      /*do functionCalls here*/
   })`

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan That is not the purpose of `.map()` :\

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `each()` should be used right?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan yep, in this case `each` seems better :-)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Yes. But we cannot decide precisely until OP opens his mouth.

Comment: @PranavCBalan What if I wrap the series of functions inside another function and pass each ID? Is that bad?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I know. `$('.fruit:visible').each(function () { /*do functionCalls here*/ });`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy What if I wrap the series of functions inside another function and pass each ID? Is that bad? The issue is that the series of function are used in other functions and I'm unable to move it inside the `map()`

Comment: From what you describe and what you have so far, you should only need to call `showInfo` while itterating your ids. If none of the functions are asynchronous then everything will just work. Normal JS execution is blocking, so there is no need to take special care regarding the order of execution. Top to bottom, that's it.

Comment: @Yoshi thank you for your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
$('#getIDs').click(function(){
   $('.fruit:visible').each(function () {
      thisId = this.id;
      showInfo( thisId, var2, var3 );
      getThumbs( thisId, newvar1);
      showRates( thisId, anothervar1, anotherVar2);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think that won't work. Because `showRates()` depends on `getThumbs()`... This series is a chain. Can not pass the ID directly to the 2nd function onwards. Also `$('.fruit:visible').each(function () { showInfo( this.id, var2, var3 ); });` can not be done because I need each ID to complete before sending the next ID.

Comment: @Bekki You can use global variables in that case. set the variable and use for the function call `showRates`

Comment: Thanks. But my main requirement is to pass an ID at a time through the series of functions before sending the next ID. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Bekki If you are not doing any AJAX calls you are good to use the functions in sequential manner.

Comment: You mean ajax calls within the chain of functions or ajax calls from other functions while these chain of functions take place?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you wanted.

Getting all the `ids` of the visible images and then passing using that to call respective functions is not a good idea.

**What I have done:**

- get all elements by `class` selector (fruit) and loop through all the images.
- Check if the current image visible inside the loop and call respective function for each image instance.

**JS Code:**

```
function showInfo( anID, var2, var3 ){
   var newvar1;
   //do something with var`s & assign result to newvar1
  return newvar1;
});
function getThumbs( anID, newvar1){
   var arr[]; 
   //do something with newvar1 and generate anothervar1, anotherVar2
   arr[0] = anothervar1;
   arr[1] = anothervar2;
   return arr;
});

// array arr contains 2 variable definitions 'anothervar1, anotherVar2'
function showRates( anID, arr){
   //final process array arr do required operation
});

$('.fruit').each(function(){
   var $curElement = $(this);
   var $id = $curElement.attr('id');
   var ret;
   if ($curElement.is(":visible")){
     //get the parameters required for the below function and pass it.
     ret = howInfo( $id, var2, var3 );
     ret = getThumbs( $id, ret);
     showRates( $id, ret);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think that won't work. Because `showRates() `depends on `getThumbs()`... This series is a chain. Can not pass the ID directly to the 2nd function on wards. Also `$('.fruit:visible').each(function () { showInfo( this.id, var2, var3 ); });` can not be done because I need each ID to complete before sending the next ID.

Comment: you mean the return value of showrates is passed to getThumbs ? also if you need the id of respective image, you can get it by using `.attr()`, var $id = $curElement.attr('id');

Comment: ID is passed to `howInfo( );`. Then `howInfo( );` passes a set of vars to `getThumbs();`. Then  `getThumbs();` passes a set of vars to `showRates();`

Comment: hmm, that aint difficult bro. you can just return the data from each of those function and pass it to next function as a parameter. anyway i have edited the code you can check it to know what im saying.